# Show only products in stock of certain category Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a question about how to show only products that are in stock in a certain category in Prestashop. The other categories must show products out of stock and products in stock but this one only in stock.

I try to edit the function getProducts in Category.php and change the line:

WHERE product_shop.`id_shop` = '.(int)$context->shop->id.'

to:

WHERE stock.`quantity` > 0 AND product_shop.`id_shop` = '.(int)$context->shop->id.'

It doesn't worked and also I don't know where to put this query in order to only affects to this category.

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an error? try to use "quantity" instead of "stock.quantity".

Also you should check id_category after $sql:

```
$sql = 'something';
if ($this->id == $targetCategoryId) { // $targetCategoryId can replace by configuration: Configuration::get('YOUR_CUSTOM_CATEGORY_ID')
    $sql .= 'AND WHERE quantity > 0';
}
```